# Batch program to delete a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to automate a little backup process of a folder from the computer to a network-drive. I found the code below to delete the folder on the network drive but I can't get it working because it says "Unable to find the specified file" for each files that it tries to remove. Why?

```
rd /s /q "\\MY SERVER\mysharename\myfolder"
```

Comment: just to be sure: `dir "\\MY SERVER\myfolder"` works?

Comment: yes it works, the directory exists. Note that myfolder has a space inside it, this is why I quoted it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a problem with concepts. It is not `"\\server\folder"`, but `"\\server\shareName"`. And you can not remove the share with a rd command.

Comment: mmm sorry, my question didn't use the path as it is. I edited it to reflect the correct situation

Comment: I've been trying, creating a server name with spaces, with shares with spaces and folders with spaces. All work, except, when the folder has spaces at the end of the name, which needs a different sintax. Please see [You cannot delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081/en-us) and try.

Comment: could the case be that the folder is on a Mac server? Also trying manually from the cmd gives me the same error, however I'm able to delete the folder via Explorer

Comment: @Stefano, are you sure there is no any character in the folder name that can be interpreted as different from command line and explorer? No unicode characters or pagecode problems?

Comment: there are no strange characters, only two dots because a folder is called something like www.testproject.dev

Comment: @Stefano: Can you test it (warning: rd) from command line `for /d %f in ("\\server\share\*www.testproject.dev*") do rd /s /q "%f"`. Or `pushd "\\server\share" && rd /s /q "www.testproject.dev" & popd `